# Spectral Theorem applied to $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

By the spectral theorem we have for a self adjoint densely defined operator $A \colon D(A) \subset \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ that there exists a uniquely determined projection valued measure $P_A$ so that
$$f(A) = \int_{\sigma(A)} f(\lambda) dP_A(\lambda)$$
for every Borel function $f$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ denote the Fourier transform.
We consider the operator $H_0$ with domain $D(H_0) = H^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $H_0\psi = -\Delta \psi$, where $\Delta$ is the Laplace operator and $H^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the Sobolev space defined by $\{f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n) \colon |p|^2 \mathcal{F}f(p) \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)\}$. It can be shown, see for example page 198 Theorem 7.17 in the linked book below, that $H_0$ is self adjoint. Hence an application of the spectral theorem to $H_0$ is justified and one can apparently verify
$$e^{-itH_0} \psi(x) = \mathcal{F}^{-1} \Big(e^{-itp^2}\mathcal{F} \psi(p)\Big)(x) \qquad (\star)$$
(this is from Gerald Teschl's book "Mathematical Methods in Quantum Mechanics" page 199 equation 7.38: [https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/book-schroe/schroe2.pdf](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Egerald/ftp/book-schroe/schroe2.pdf)). Does anyone know how formula $(\star)$ is derived?

Comment: I couldn't find your formula $(\star)$ on p.$210$ of the cited reference.  Assuming $\ \hat{\psi}\ $ is synonymous with $\ \mathcal{F}\psi\ $, it would appear to be equation $(7.38)$ on p.$199$.

Comment: @lonza leggiera Yes it's page 199! Sorry for that, corrected that typo in my question!

Comment: The spectral theorem does not simply hold for any densely defined operator, but only for normal ones (I think Teschl only deals with self-adjoint ones). That's a big difference. So as a first step, you will have to define $H_0$ properly, including its domain.

Comment: @MaoWao Thank you, I fixed the post accordingly.

Comment: I believe there's a typo in equation $(7.38)$. I think it should be
$$
e^{-itH_0}\psi(x)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\big(e^{-itp^2}\hat{\psi}(p)\big)(x)\ .
$$
As such, it seems to be just a special case of equation $(7.35)$ in which $\ f(p)\ $ is taken to be $\ e^{-itp^2}\ $.  This latter equation also appears to me to be very confusingly written, in that the symbol "$p$" on its left side seems to represent a different operator $\big($viz. $\ i^{-1}\frac{d}{dx}\ \big)$ from what it does on the left (where it seems to represent multiplication by the real argument of $\ \hat{\psi}(p)\ $).

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Does he not state in 7.35 that this would be an alternative way to define functions of $H_0$? How can we be sure whether or not this agrees with the approach of using the spectral theorem?

Comment: @lonzaleggiera I agree, the brackets should be the way you put them. I corrected that in the post.

Comment: @h3fr43nd Yes, that's my reading of what equation $(7.35)$ is too.  It's justification might be obvious to someone who's more familiar with spectral measures than I now am, but I certainly wouldn't say it's *obvious* to me (although it does seem very plausible).

Comment: @lonzaleggiera I got a solution now :)

Comment: Well done!$\ \ \ $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{H}$ and $\tilde{\mathcal{H}}$ be two Hilbert spaces. Recall that a map $\mathcal{U} \colon \mathcal{H} \to \tilde{\mathcal{H}}$ is called a unitary isomorphism between $\mathcal{H}$ and $\tilde{\mathcal{H}}$ if $\mathcal{U}$ is linear, bijective and $\|\mathcal{U}\psi\| = \|\psi\|$ for all $\psi \in \mathcal{H}$. If $A \colon D(A) \subset \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ and $\tilde{A} \colon D(\tilde{A}) \subset \tilde{\mathcal{H}} \to \tilde{\mathcal{H}}$ are two densely defined operators, then we say $A$ and $\tilde{A}$ are unitarily equivalent if there exists a unitary isomorphism $\mathcal{U} \colon \mathcal{H} \to \tilde{\mathcal{H}}$ so that
$$\mathcal{U}A = \tilde{A}\mathcal{U} \qquad \mathcal{U}D(A) = D(\tilde{A})$$
Now note that if $A$ and $\tilde{A}$ are unitarily equivalent (by means of $\mathcal{U}$) as above, then we have
$$d\mu_{\varphi,\psi} = d\tilde{\mu}_{\mathcal{U}\varphi,\mathcal{U}\psi}$$
for all $\varphi,\psi \in \mathcal{H}$, where $d\mu_{\varphi,\psi}$ is the corresponding spectral measure for $A$ with respect to the vectors $\varphi,\psi$ and $d\tilde{\mu}_{\mathcal{U}\varphi,\mathcal{U}\psi}$ is the corresponding spectral measure for $\tilde{A}$ with respect to the vectors $\mathcal{U}\varphi,\mathcal{U}\psi$. This can be seen as follows:
Let $R_A, R_{\tilde{A}}$ be the respective resolvents, then $\mathcal{U}R_A(z)\mathcal{U}^{-1} = R_{\tilde{A}}(z)$ is easily seen. But then
$$\int \frac{1}{\lambda-z} d\mu_{\varphi,\psi}(\lambda) = \langle \varphi \mid R_A(z) \psi\rangle = \langle \mathcal{U}\varphi \mid R_{\tilde{A}}(z)\mathcal{U}\psi\rangle = \int \frac{1}{\lambda-z} d\tilde{\mu}_{\mathcal{U}\varphi,\mathcal{U}\psi}(\lambda)$$
But the Borel transform of a Borel measure is uniquely determined and hence $d\mu_{\varphi,\psi} = d\tilde{\mu}_{\mathcal{U}\varphi,\mathcal{U}\psi}$, as wanted. But then we also
$$\mathcal{U}f(A) = f(\tilde{A})\mathcal{U}$$ for every (bounded) Borel function $f$, since
$$\langle \varphi \mid f(A)\psi\rangle = \int f(\lambda) d\mu_{\varphi, \psi}(\lambda) = \int f(\lambda)d\mu_{\mathcal{U}\varphi, \mathcal{U}\psi}(\lambda)= \langle \mathcal{U}\varphi \mid f(\tilde{A})\mathcal{U}\psi\rangle = \langle \varphi \mid \mathcal{U}^{-1}f(\tilde{A})\mathcal{U}\psi\rangle$$
holds for all $\varphi, \psi \in \mathcal{H}$.

Now the last ingredient in all this is that for $H_0 = -\Delta$ with $D(H_0) = H^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ we have the unitary equivalence
$$\mathcal{F}H_0\mathcal{F}^{-1} = |p|^2$$ where $|p|^2$ is the maximally defined multiplication operator with domain $\{\varphi \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n) \mid |p|^2\varphi(p) \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)\}$. With that in our toolbox equation $(\star)$ is obvious, since for $f(z) = e^{-izt}$ we have
$$e^{-itH_0} = f(H_0) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}f(|p|^2)\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{F}^{-1}e^{-it|p|^2}\mathcal{F}$$ as wanted.